# Font name being misparsed in Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, fonts, fabricjs

I'm trying to use a Google font with the unfortunate name of "Slabo 27px" in an HTML Canvas. I'm creating a fabric.js Text object and setting the fontFamily value to the font name. It always draws at the same size regardless of how I set the fontSize. I'm guessing that fabric.js is passing the name to the canvas font property, which is defined as equivalent to a CSS style, and canvas is parsing the 27px as a text size.

I've tried putting the name in quotes and leaving out the 27px, but those don't help. Is there any trick that will get canvas to treat "Slabo 27px" as just a font name?

Comment: Can you change the `font-family` name that the @font-face rule sets up? If so, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pomax's comment gave me the clue I needed. The "font" which is linked to is a short bit of CSS that includes a font-family declaration and a URL to the font data. I downloaded this to a local CSS file, changed the font-family to "Slabo," and linked to the local CSS instead of to Google. Now the font works.